# How to show a message in the login page if the login fails using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, servlets

I have developed a login page where the user id and minmum password length validation is done by JavaScript and I have a servlet that connects to DB and authenticates the user. Can someone please tell me how to display a message in the same login page when authentication fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send a flag value of login failed from your servlet like this.

```
request.setAttribute("loginResult", true);
```

Now get this value in JSP. Its default value will be false. if its true then show error message.

```
<%
    if(request.getAttribute("loginResult") != null && request.getAttribute("loginResult") == "true"){
%>
 <p style="color:red"> Login Failed. Please try again. </p>
<%
}
%>
```

For Javascript call a function to show error, instead of      `<p style="color:red"> Login Failed. Please try again. </p>` from my above code.

Comment: After `req.setAttribute("loginResult", true)` operation in servlet, should I forward the request back to the JSP page? Like here:
`RequestDispatcher rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp");
rd.forward(req, response);`

Answer (score 3):

HTML (place this in the page's HTML where the error message should be displayed):

```
<span id="login_failed"></span>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var login_success = false;  /* set this to true if the login was a success */

if(login_success == false)
{
    document.getElementById("login_failed").innerHTML = "Login Failed.";
}
else
{
     window.location = "http://www.yourpage.com/login_success.html";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

in your web.xml put this

```
<login-config>
  <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
  <form-login-config>
    <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
    <form-error-page>/login.jsp?loginerror=100</form-error-page>
  </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

now in your login.jsp put this javascript to read the loginerror param and call it ondocument.ready (onload())

```
function gup()
{
  var name = 'loginerror';
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
  if( results == null )
    //here you don't have login errors
  else
    //here you have login error
}
```

enjoy

Answer (score 0):

```
if(/*something fails*/){
    alert("Login fails!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Print the JavaScript in Servlet.

- The alert message:

  ```
  System.out.println("<script>alert('Login fail.')</script>");
  ```
- Redirect to login page again:

  ```
  System.out.println("<script>window.location='loginUrl'</script>");
  ```